# HTML content displaying label

Tags: asp.net

I am using an ASP.NET Label control.

```
<asp:Label ID="LblDescription" runat="server">

LblDescription.Text="Html Tables or/and Texts"
```

I want to display the content of an editor to this field. My editor can contain text as well as tables.

So if I include labels, how can I display this table to this label? Because table is in HTML format.

I saved the data as `nvarchar`. So I can retrieve the data from database but I can't access the value in `label.text` field.

How is this possible? Or is there any other control that meets this requirement?

Comment: Have a look at [LiteralControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: ¿? I cannot understand what are you asking for...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert tables coming from the database, obviously a ´Label´ control is not the proper place due this control is rendered as a span.

You have, for example, the `ControlPlaceHolder` or the `LiteralControl`. If it is a regular HTML table, I will choose the second one.